# Timeout on Z3 query with simple datatype

Tags: z3

I created the following datatype to be an encoding for the set of the integers union infinity and minus infinity, with the comparison operator `<=` redefined over this new datatype:

```
(declare-datatypes ((AugInt 0)) (((infty) (ninfty) (integer (val Int)))))
(declare-fun <= (AugInt AugInt) Bool)
(declare-fun <= (AugInt Int) Bool)
(declare-fun <= (Int AugInt) Bool)
(assert (forall ((x AugInt) (y AugInt))
  (let ((a!1 (ite ((_ is (infty () AugInt)) y)
                  true
                  (ite ((_ is (ninfty () AugInt)) y) false (<= (val x) (val y))))))
    (= (<= x y)
       (ite ((_ is (infty () AugInt)) x)
            (= y infty)
            (ite ((_ is (ninfty () AugInt)) x) true a!1))))))
(assert (forall ((x AugInt) (y Int)) (= (<= x y) (<= x (integer y)))))
(assert (forall ((x Int) (y AugInt)) (= (<= x y) (<= (integer x) y))))
```

My goal from here is to give Z3 a query over this datatype, and first determine if the query is satisfiable, and if so then return a model. Currently, a satisfiable query like the following terminates and returns a valid model:

```
(declare-fun r1_B () AugInt)
(declare-fun l1_B () AugInt)
(assert (forall ((out Int) ($c0 Int) ($c2 Int) ($c4 Int))
  (let ((a!1 (or (= out 1)
                 (and (= out (+ $c0 $c2))
                      (<= l1_B $c0)
                      (<= $c0 r1_B)
                      (<= l1_B $c2)
                      (<= $c2 r1_B)))))
    (=> a!1 (and (<= l1_B out) (<= out r1_B))))))
(assert (and (<= ninfty l1_B)
     (<= r1_B infty)
     (or (not (= ninfty l1_B)) (not (= infty r1_B)))))
```

For queries that are unsatisfiable, on the other hand, Z3 will timeout without terminating, as it likely cannot prove such a query:

```
(declare-fun r1_B () AugInt)
(declare-fun l1_B () AugInt)
(assert (forall ((out Int) ($c0 Int) ($c2 Int) ($c4 Int))
  (let ((a!1 (or (= out 1)
                 (and (= out (+ $c0 $c2))
                      (<= l1_B $c0)
                      (<= $c0 r1_B)
                      (<= l1_B $c2)
                      (<= $c2 r1_B)))))
    (=> a!1 (and (<= l1_B out) (<= out r1_B))))))
(assert (and (<= 1 l1_B)
     (<= r1_B infty)
     (or (not (= (integer 1) l1_B)) (not (= infty r1_B)))))
```

I tried adding the option `sat.smt=true` to give it a newer quantifier elimination core, but then I get the inverse problem, namely where it now is able to prove the UNSAT query, but the new core now is unable to prove the satisfiable query. I want to be able to determine if the query is satisfiable or not, so I can't just choose to apply or not apply the `sat.smt=true` option a priori. Any ideas on how to get Z3 to compute either query without timing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While SMTLib allows for overloading of theory symbols (i.e., `<=` in your case), I think this usage is confusing at best. Note that user-defined functions cannot be overloaded like this, and typically the theory-symbol overloading is left to the internal theory declarations, not to user-space definitions. I'd shy away from using this feature: In fact I'm not even sure if this is totally legitimate. For instance, CVC5 rejects your script with:

```
(error "Parse Error: a.smt2:2.14: Symbol `<=' is shadowing a theory function symbol")
```

I'm not sure what's going on with z3. They might have an extension to support such usage, but it's not compliant and definitely not portable. In any case, I wouldn't trust this feature. It might be throwing z3 off.

Secondly: Avoid quantifiers as much as you possibly can. Instead, prefer pure definitions, which are much better supported.

So, I'd code your program as follows:

```
(declare-datatype AugInt ((infty) (ninfty) (integer (val Int))))

(define-fun leAA ((x AugInt) (y AugInt)) Bool
            (or ((_ is ninfty) x)
                ((_ is  infty) y)
                (and ((_ is integer) x)
                     ((_ is integer) y)
                     (<= (val x) (val y)))))

(define-fun leAI ((x AugInt) (y Int   )) Bool (leAA x           (integer y)))
(define-fun leIA ((x Int)    (y AugInt)) Bool (leAA (integer x) y))

(declare-fun r1_B () AugInt)
(declare-fun l1_B () AugInt)

(assert (forall ((out Int) ($c0 Int) ($c2 Int) ($c4 Int))
  (let ((a!1 (or (= out 1)
                 (and (= out (+ $c0 $c2))
                      (leAI l1_B $c0)
                      (leIA $c0 r1_B)
                      (leAI l1_B $c2)
                      (leIA $c2 r1_B)))))
    (=> a!1 (and (leAI l1_B out) (leIA out r1_B))))))

(assert (and (leAA ninfty l1_B)
             (leAA r1_B infty)
             (or (not (= ninfty l1_B)) (not (= infty r1_B)))))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

When I run this, I get:

```
sat
(
  (define-fun l1_B () AugInt
    (integer 0))
  (define-fun r1_B () AugInt
    infty)
)
```

successfully producing a model. When I try your second query:

```
(assert (forall ((out Int) ($c0 Int) ($c2 Int) ($c4 Int))
  (let ((a!1 (or (= out 1)
                 (and (= out (+ $c0 $c2))
                      (leAI l1_B $c0)
                      (leIA $c0 r1_B)
                      (leAI l1_B $c2)
                      (leIA $c2 r1_B)))))
    (=> a!1 (and (leAI l1_B out) (leIA out r1_B))))))

(assert (and (leIA 1 l1_B)
             (leAA r1_B infty)
             (or (not (= (integer 1) l1_B)) (not (= infty r1_B)))))
(check-sat)
```

I get:

```
unsat
```

which is what you were expecting.